# Complete data with a query of the same form data in php

Tags: php, html

I want to use a php code to return an email based on a query with another data from the same form?

For example, I have a table with 2 columns, user and email, the user complete the form with the username that match with the user column in the DB, and then the email filled is complete with the email column value without use a submit button.

I only have a continue button between steps.

Exists anyway to do this?

Regards

Comment: You have some code to show us?

Comment: Yes.  A way to do this exists.  You're going to need to make an ajax request with Javascript.  Past that, this question is far too broad.  You are expected to make an attempt to solve your problem before posting a question.  As it stands, we don't even know if you know how to write an SQL query to fetch one value based on another.

Comment: Hi there. You would need to provide more information, and ideally code showing what you tried already. You should read this and amend your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask